# restrinct with clausole "instr" outlook and vb

Tags: vb6

```
Set olItm = olFld.Items.Restrict("[SenderName]='gss.italy@iol.it'")
```

Is possible instead to use the sendername i need to restrict by subbject with a clausole insrt?

Example:

```
Set olItm = olFld.Items.Restrict("[Subject]=instr("test")")
```

i have used the line above but have error!
Tks.

Answer (score 0):

[Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147583%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _
         & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) _
         & " like '%test%'"
Set olItm = olFld.Items.Restrict(criteria)
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  If you find an answer useful you can vote it up (click on the "up" triangle) and/or accept it (click on the checkbox).